# Creating subclass vc extending class

Tags: ios, class, oop, design-patterns, subclass

I have list of resort items.

I have class Resort that stores that items.

Now I need to add opportunity to that class to have one resort as active.

So I will save that resort to UserDefaults.

I will need method 'save', 'load', 'check if current resort is active'.

So, should I extend Resort class for that methods and properties or the better way is to create Class ActiveResort ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more of a design opinion question. Personally, I would have everything related to a `Resort` as part of the `Resort` class or extension. This is because a resort and active resort are the same structurally other than the flag that one is active, if I understood correctly.

Perhaps make a class method called `activeResort` that returns the `Resort` instance this is currently active